# Order of channels in BufferedImage?

Tags: java, java-2d, bufferedimage

How do I find out the order of color channels in a BufferedImage (different types including alpha channels)?

I need to know the order of R, G, and B parameters for operations like LookupOp (order of byte[][] in ByteLookupTable(int, byte[][])) or RescaleOp(float[], float[], hints).

Is there a generic way to find the order from a given BufferedImage? I thought it should be in the ColorModel but I can't find it.

I have used code like `if (t == BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)` but there must be better ways, right?

Comment: Clarification: What I am looking for is the information if I need to put the lookup tables I have for R, G, and B in the LookupOp in RGB, BRG, RGBA or even another order.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is split between
[SampleModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/SampleModel.html) and [ColorModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html).

The `SampleModel` describes how the data is organized which allows you to get the data for one or more pixels. (You get a `SampleModel` by calling `bi.getData().getSampleModel(),` where bi is a BufferedImage).

`ColorModel` then provides methods (`getAlpha`, `getRed`, `getGreen`, `GetBlue`) for getting the ARGB components from a pixel.

**Addendum:**

I think the way you use this is:

```
    BufferedImage bi = ...;
    Raster r = bi.getData();
    // Use the sample model to get the pixel
    SampleModel sm = r.getSampleModel();
    Object pixel = sm.getPixel(0, 0, (int[])null, r.getDataBuffer());
    // Use the color model to get the red value from the pixel
    ColorModel cm = bi.getColorModel();
    int red = cm.getRed(pixel[0]);
```

This looks like it would be very flexible for handling any color/sample model you may encounter, but I can't imagine the performance would be spectacular. I'd probably use this model agnostic approach to convert the image to `TYPE_INT_ARGB` where the layout is well documented, then manipulate the data directly. Then, if necessary, convert it back to the original form.

Comment: The link to SampleModel was new to me but I still don't find the information about the order of channels I have to provide for e.g. LookupOp. I know that I can getRed() from the ColorModel for a pixel but how do I know where in the order of channels red is?