# Get RGB components from ColorModel

Tags: java, colors, rgb, pixel, raster

I want to extract the R,G and B values of the pixels of an image. I do it in two ways.

```
File img_file = new File("../foo.png");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(img_file);
```

1st method(which works fine):

```
img.getRaster().getPixel(i, j, rgb);
```

2nd method(which throws new IllegalArgumentException("More than one component per pixel"))

```
red = img.getColorModel().getRed(img.getRGB(i, j));
```

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Normally when I want to extract RGB from a `BufferedImage` I do something like this:

```
File img_file = new File("../foo.png");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(img_file);

Color color = new Color(img.getRGB(i,j));
int red = color.getRed();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html#getRed%28int%29)

> An IllegalArgumentException is thrown if pixel values for this
>   ColorModel are not conveniently representable as a single int

It would suggest that the underlying color model is representable by a single `int` value

You may also want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282366/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-more-than-one-component-per-pixel) for some more details

Typically, you would simply take the `int` packed pixel from the image and use `Color` to generate a `Color` representation and then extract the values from there...

First, get the `int` packed value of the pixel at `x/y`...

```
int pixel = img.getRGB(i, j);
```

Use this to construct a `Color` object...

```
Color color = new Color(pixel, true); // True if you care about the alpha value...
```

Extract the R, G, B values...

```
int red = color.getRed();
int green = color.getGreen();
int blue = color.getBlue();
```

Now you could simply do some bit maths, but this is simpler and is more readable - IMHO

Comment: thanks for the response. but how do you determine whether the color model is representable by a single int value?

Comment: Personally, I'd be checking to see if it's an `instanceof` `ComponentColorModel`, `IndexColorModel` or `PackedColorModel`, but you could also test what `getNumColorComponents`, `getNumComponents` and `getPixelSize` return...

Comment: @Rayhunter, `BufferedImage` only supports up to 32-bit types so all pixels will fit in a Java int (see supported types http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_3BYTE_BGR)

Comment: I've just noticed that `int pxl = img.getRGB(i, j);` returns `-1`, which is wierd, at least for me.

Comment: @Rayhunter Nope, this perfectly normal and has to with how the packed `int` deals with/allows overflow.  Remember the `int` value a packed series of `byte`